# React-Native footer is not static

Tags: react-native

I Created a footer for a react-native application. It is not fixed to the bottom. When the keyboard is on, the footer also moves to the upwards. This is my code. How can I have a fixed footer to the bottom?

```
export const TabNavFooter = TabNavigator(
  {
    mainfeed: { screen: MainFeedScreen },
    workout: { screen: WorkoutScreen },
    videos: { screen: VideosScreen },
    chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
    profile: { screen: ProfilePageScreen }
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === "chat") {
          iconName = `message${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`;
        } else if (routeName === "profile") {
          iconName = `account${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`;
        }

        return <Icon name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      }
    }),
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "blue",
      inactiveTintColor: "gray"
    },
    swipeEnabled: false,
    lazyLoad: true,
    animationEnabled: false
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't happen generally unless the there is some overlay component over the Tabs that you're trying to focus.

To fix the TabBar to the bottom of the screen you add the `tab styles` as

```
tabBarOptions: {
            //... Other props
            style: {
                position: 'absolute',
                bottom: 0,
                right: 0,
                left: 0,
                height: 54,
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Pritish for the answer

Comment: This style will move the `tabBar` to the `bottom` of the component in which `tab` was defined in, if there is some spacing, then that means there would be some wrapper around it.

Comment: Hi Pritish -
With the keyboard, still the footer comes up to the keyboard.

Comment: That was my concern too, there seems an overlay element in play, therefore you might need to post the code [here](https://snack.expo.io), just the sample to reproduce with dummy values.